# Just how involved are Explorators in their surroundings?

Tags: rogue-trader

Tech Priests would not give the time of day to another fleshling if it had nothing to do with anything mechanical, electrical, or remotely linked to the Machine God. However, Explorators seem to be a little more open minded -

> An Explorator is an Adeptus Mechanicus Tech-priest who is dedicated to the exploration and exploitation of new worlds and new regions of the galaxy for the Imperium of Man. They act as part adventurer, part warrior and part emissary of the Machine Cult of Mars.

In our game, my Explorator is becoming more and more involved in the mechanical side of things. In our last session, the team were attempting to come up with a plan for there next encounter, while the Explorator was paying no attention and was purely interested in the mechanical arm of one of the NPCs.

What level of devotion to the Machines vs. their expeditions should an Explorator have? For example would he be more interested in the Kroot Homeworld or a control panel?

Comment: I think this is primarily opinion-based because it really comes down to this: what does *the player* think the PC should do, in order to be "dedicated to the exploration and exploitation of new worlds and new regions of the galaxy for the Imperium of Man"? Finding the balance between control panel and Kroot Homeworld that most shows that dedication is their challenge and prerogative as a roleplayer; and different Explorators will choose/show slightly different balances anyway, which is also a roleplayer's prerogative. So yeah: it's a matter of taste and opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the character's personality. Explorators are sent to explore, recover extremely valuable archeotech and report new forms of life. They're basically that, intrepid explorers, all while being tech-priests.

If your friend has an obsession with the machines it's not bad, as tech-priests are, but if he doesn't focus on the expedition you could say he's not doing a very good job as an Explorator.

As for the last question, it depends. If the control pannel is part of ancient technology or even alien technology, then he should put all his focus on it. If it's a regular imperial panel that has no real value, he should put his focus elsewhere (unless the panel itself is important to the mission)

Long story short, all tech-priests have a devotion for machines, but that shouldn't keep them from doing their tasks, specially for an Explorator. Then again, if that's the character's personality and that's how your player wants to roll, you can't really say he's doing anything wrong. However, other crewmembers should point out his lack of competence.